# CSS finished font downloading

Tags: jquery, css

I am using `@font-face` in `CSS`. The `font ttf` is 400 kb so takes time to load. I want to check when the font has downloaded completely so after that I can make the Text `Label` visible. How can I do it in `jQuery`?

Because before the font is not downloaded the site displays `Label` with default Arial font which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I use timers...

```
var item = $('.myclass');// check an item width before setting its font family;
var itemWidth = item.width(); // store initial width
$('.myclass').addClass('setfont'); // add your font family via css
function checkFont(){
    if( item.width() == itemWidth ){
        setTimeout(checkFont); 
    } else {
        setTimeout(fontLoaded,300); // I have a 300 ms bug....You can try call fontLoaded without this timer
    }
}
setTimeout(checkFont);

function fontLoaded(){
//....do stuff
}
```

Comment: But if the contents of the element changes or the page is resized this won't work..

Comment: well you do this just one time, at onload event

Comment: What if one's internet is painfully slow and they resize the window while the font is loading initially?

Comment: well...in this case, you can add a 'ghost' element positioned outside of the window, and check that element width :). For example let have a tag <span style="position:fixed;left:-2000px;top:-2000px" id="elemToCheck">text</span>